# Interfaces aninhadas não estáticas podem ser usadas independente de instância da classe que a enclausura?

Tags: java, interface

Estava lendo sobre [`JsInterop`](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJsInterop.html) e me deparo com um exemplo de código:

```java
package com.example;

@JsType
public class Bar {
    @JsFunction
    public interface Foo {
        int exec(int x);
    }

    public static int action1(Foo foo) {
        return foo.exec(40);
    }

    public static Foo action2() {
        return (x) -> x + 2;
    }
}
```

> A pergunta não tem nada com `JsInterop`, foi só onde eu peguei o exemplo

Note que, aqui, `Foo` é uma interface aninhada *dentro* da classe `Bar`. Diferente do que estou acostumado a ver com *classes aninhadas*, `Foo` não está anotada como estática.

Eu sei que, se a classe aninhada não for declarada como estática, como por exemplo:

```java
package com.example;

public class Marm {

  public class Ota {
  }
}
```

toda instância da classe `Ota` tem uma referência para `Marm.this`, passada como argumento implícito para o seu construtor, podendo então acessar os campos e métodos privados da classe que a encapsula:

```java
package com.example;

public class Marm {

    public class Ota {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "" + Marm.this.n;
        }
    }

    private int n;
    public Marm(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Ota a;
        // se eu fizesse: a = new Ota();
        // teria este erro: No enclosing instance of type Marm is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Marm (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Marm).
        a = new Marm(5).new Ota();
        System.out.println(a); // imprime 5
    }
}
```

Porém, eu fico com uma dúvida: uma interface aninhada tem o mesmo efeito se ela fosse "estática"? E, com Java 8 permitindo métodos `default` em interfaces, as interfaces aninhadas estão alheias ao `Marm.this` e não poderiam referenciá-lo?

E, aproveitando, e quanto aos métodos privados e estáticos da classe que a enclausura, os métodos `default` poderiam ter acesso a eles?

Comment: Uma interface aninhada é `static` por *default*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1

Comment: @hkotsubo, resposta por RTFM, curti. Se não tive duplicação (acho que não), acho que vale a pena uma resposta, por mais breve que seja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1), uma interface aninhada é `static` por *default*. Ou seja, as duas formas abaixo são equivalentes:

```
public class Foo {
    public interface Bar {
        void fazAlgo();
    }
}

// ou
public class Foo {
    public static interface Bar {
        void fazAlgo();
    }
}
```

Em ambos os casos, a interface será usada da mesma maneira (de forma estática):

```
package outro.pacote.completamente.diferente;

import pacote.onde.esta.foobar.Foo;

public class TestFoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo.Bar bar = new Foo.Bar() {
            @Override
            public void fazAlgo() {
                System.out.println("fazendo algo");
            }
        };
        bar.fazAlgo(); // imprime "fazendo algo"
    }
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
// importando direto a interface
import pacote.onde.esta.foobar.Foo.Bar;

public class TestFoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = () -> {
            System.out.println("fazendo algo");
        };
        bar.fazAlgo();
    }
}
```

> *No exemplo acima, poderia-se inclusive anotar a interface `Bar` com `@FunctionalInterface`, embora a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) diga que não é obrigatório: "**the compiler will treat any interface meeting the [definition of a functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) as a functional interface regardless of whether or not a FunctionalInterface annotation is present on the interface declaration**"*.

Importante notar que continuam valendo as regras de visibilidade: se a interface não fosse `public`, a classe `TestFoo` não conseguiria enxergá-la.

E qualquer tentativa de acessar a interface de maneira não-estática dará erro de compilação. Ex:

```
Foo.Bar b = new Foo().new Bar() { // error: anonymous class implements interface; cannot have qualifier for new
    // etc...
};
```

---

Então para resumir:

> *Uma interface aninhada tem o mesmo efeito se ela fosse "estática"?*

Uma interface aninhada sempre é estática.

> *E, com Java 8 permitindo métodos `default` em interfaces, as interfaces aninhadas estão alheias ao `Marm.this` e não poderiam referenciá-lo?*

Como elas são `static`, não estão associadas a uma instância específica e por isso não conseguem referenciar o `this` da classe externa. Então o código abaixo não compila:

```
public class Foo {

    private int x;

    public interface Bar {    
        void fazAlgo();

        default void metodoDefault() {
           // error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
           System.out.println(Foo.this.x);
        }
    }
}
```

> *E, aproveitando, e quanto aos métodos privados e estáticos da classe que a enclausura, os métodos `default` poderiam ter acesso a eles?*

Para os métodos privados, ocorre o mesmo problema acima. Como a interface `Bar` não consegue acessar `Foo.this`, então ela não consegue acessar os métodos privados de `Foo`.

Já para os métodos estáticos, não há problema nenhum em acessá-los:

```
public class Foo {
    static void fooStatic() {
        System.out.println("método estático de Foo");
    }

    public interface Bar {
        void fazAlgo();

        default void metodoDefault() {
            Foo.fooStatic();
        }
    }
}

public class TestFoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo.Bar bar = () -> {};
        bar.metodoDefault(); // imprime "método estático de Foo"
    }
}
```

Lembrando que um método `default` de uma interface [é automaticamente `public`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html), por isso eu consigo chamá-lo no exemplo acima.

Também é interessante notar que o exemplo acima funcionaria mesmo se o método `fooStatic` fosse `private`.